# Selenium Python Pull Data from Dynamic Table that refreshes every 5 seconds

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to pull data from a real time table/dashboard that refreshes every 5 seconds. Because it refreshes every 5 seconds, it gives me incomplete records[I think starting from row 1 until it refreshes]. Is there a solution to this problem where I can disable autorefresh for some time, may be 15 seconds?

Comment: Can you please share your site, code so far and more details on the problem  you're experiencing (examples instead of incomplete records) ? - there are methods of controlling a page you have open but it depends on the technology

Comment: Hello @RichEdwards. Thank you so much for your response. The site is unfortunately unshareable. I am trying to all rows from a table that refreshes every 5 seconds. response= driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div[class^='ui-widget-content slick-row']")
for res in response:
    print(res.text)                                                                                                                              The problem is the table has columns that the values refresh in real time so when it has 400 rows I am getting like only 50 rows.

Comment: You're looking at a site that 400 rows of data that refreshes every 5 seconds? and you to digest *all of that* 5 seconds? - you can't provide the site or similar demo so i can't test it to provide a real answer.I'd assume your site is probably doing async js calls - Opt 1: look at devtools Network tab to see the post/get and do those calls via API.  Option 2 - override the js update-call with your own empty function: `ScriptParentNameHere = function(){}`  - look at the scripts in your page for the name - i can't give you more than this unless you have a site for me to play

Comment: @RichEdwards I really appreciate your detailed feedback. The closest thing that I could think was this http://www.emojitracker.com/ so when you see this site you see the columns refresh every second or even in less time. My problem is similar, I am trying to storeText from the table so that I could get all rows but I think the because of javascript and autorefresh the page changes its state and I get incomplete records. Thank you for the suggestions above though. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use requests and get the page, then the data would be complete.

```
import requests
import time

while True:
    url = "insert url here"
    page = requests.get(url)

    # Parse data

    time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I am going into a site logging in using selenium and then only getting to the page that has the table. It is not a direct link. Do you think it still works?

Answer (score 0):

From the comments you have a couple of approaches. As you're unable to share you're site, the best i can do is describe what you need to do and how i got your equivalent site working.

Both approaches use http://www.emojitracker.com/ as an example site.

**Approach 1** - get your data at the network layer:

- Go to your site in chrome.
- Open devtools
- Go to the network tab
- Find the call that pull down your data  - you're looking for the GET

For the example site provided, i can see i have an entry called `rankings` like so:
[image: devtool networking]

The `HEADERS` tab describes the data you need. For this site there's no auth, there's nothing special and i don't need to send any payload. It's just the API and method that is needed:

```
Request URL: http://www.emojitracker.com/api/rankings
Request Method: GET
```

Couldn't be simpler to throw that into pyhton:

```py
import requests

response = requests.get("http://www.emojitracker.com/api/rankings")
data = response.json()
for line in data:
    print(line['id'])
    print(line['score'])
```

That prints out the score and the ID from the json response. This is how we look when debugging:
[image: debugging in vscode]

---

**Approach 2** - Hacking the javascript

- Go to the site, let the page load
- go to devtools
- go to the console
- select the source tab and pause the javascript (top right corner) - pay attention to where the cursor stops. Restart and pause a few times and note the different functions involved. Also look at what they do the discern other functions involved.

When you're ready - go to the console tab and type `this.stop()`.
On the site you provided, this stops the update-calls.

This should give you the time you need to get your data.

From here, you have two choices to get your data going again.

1. The simplest way is to just refresh the page. This will restart the page with new, streaming data.
   Do this with:

```
driver.refresh()
```

2. The more fun way, read the js and figure out how to restart the stream!
   Use the console's intellisense to help you.

Reviewing the JS, where it paused (from steps above), and a bit trial and error I found:

```
this.startRawScoreStreaming()
```

It does this output

```
application.js:90 Subscribing to score stream (raw)
ƒ (event) {
      return incrementScore(event.data);
    }
```

And the page start streaming again.

Finally, to run these JS snippets in selenium - you use `.execute_script`

```
driver.execute_script('this.stop()')
## do your stuff
driver.execute_script('this.startRawScoreStreaming()')
```

Comment: Hello @RichEdwards. Thank you so so much for your detailed suggestion. My question now is the site that has the real time table is behind the login site and was wondering if using request after the login would delete the session. So, I was wondering is there a way to login, and then make a request that would not require me logging again.

Comment: My coderight now is something like this.  Can I  selenium remember user name and password from before                                                                                   driver.get("ht.aspx")
//login
# response = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("//*[text()[contains(.,'ui-widget-content slick-row odd realTimeGridOddRow')]]")
# response = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@id, 'agentList_')]")
driver.execute_script("this.stop()")
response = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div[class^='ui-widget-content slick-row']")
for res in response:
    print(res.text)

Comment: @KharelJi on stackoverflow we say thanks by marking questions are correct or useful. When using Requests it doesn't remove your session. It doesn't know what your session is. You need to share your authentication state between your browser and requests. Typically this is done by sharing cookies - but as I can't aww your site I can't say for sure

Comment: Thanks again. Sorry I am not too familiar with stack overflow technicalities. Thanks for letting me know and I will definitely remember from now on.